# how to generate a graph using 'random' and 'networkX' libraries?

Tags: python-3.x, random, graph, networkx

I have an assignment where I have to create a `graph` using the `random library` with for loops and also compute the `probability` whether there is an edge between two `vertices`. The body of the code is as given below.

How can I construct an `graph`?

```
# generate edges in G_rand at random:
for i in range(0,k) :
    for j in range(0,i) : 
        # Add an edge between vertices i and j, with probability edge_probab 
        # ...
```

Comment: Please don't use all upper-case sentences, not even in your title. It's considered shouting, and is rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import random
import networkx as nx

edge_probability = 0.3
n_nodes = 10

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(range(n_nodes))

for u in G.nodes:
    for v in G.nodes:
        if random.random() < edge_probability:
            G.add_edge(u, v)
```

[image: Graph generated randomly]